# How to get values of XML node filtering by attribute name in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode, xml-attribute

This is part of my XML file

```
<summary>
  <testcase>  
    <result value="-45">100</result>
    <result value="0">200</result>
    <result value="45">300</result>
  </testcase>
  <testcase>    
    <result value="-45">1000</result>
    <result value="0">2000</result>
    <result value="45">3000</result>
  </testcase>  
 <testcase>    
    <result value="-45">0.1</result>
    <result value="0">0.2</result>
    <result value="45">0.3</result>
  </testcase>
</summary>
```

I need to get element values by filtering by Attribute name.

> As an Example I need to get all values where attribute = 45 Then
>   Answer is 300,3000,0.3

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(_xmlFilePath);
XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("//testcase");

for (int i = 0; i < nodelist.Count; i++)
{
    Double value;                        
    Double.TryParse(nodelist[i].SelectSingleNode("result").Attributes["45"].InnerText, out value);
    Console.WriteLine("value : " + value);
}
```

but above code gives following error message.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any suggestion is appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this may help you to solve your problem

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(_xmlFilePath);
XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("//result[@value=45]");
for (int i = 0; i < nodelist.Count; i++)
{
    double value = double.Parse(nodelist[i].InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine("value : " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
XDocument xdc = XDocument.Load(YourXMLFile);
var rslt = xdc.Descendants("result").Where(x => x.Attribute("value").Value == "45");
string rsltstr = string.Empty;
foreach(XElement el in rslt)
{
    rsltstr = rsltstr + el.Value + ", ";
}
```

or

```
var rslt = xdc.Descendants("result")
              .Where(x => x.Attribute("value").Value == "45")
              .Select(q=>q.Value);
```